Filament CheckListbox - Extra Pivot table data
How can I return the amenity_type_id from my Amenity model, as the CheckBoxList uses by default the pluck() method and I'm not sure how to get fields id, name, as well as amenity_type_id so it can be saved to the pivot table amenity_property.
amenity_property table consists of:
amenity_id, property_id, amenity_type_id
$record->amenity_type_id value always is null because it's not available in the collection.
$options = Amenity::all()->pluck('name', 'id');

CheckboxList::make('amenities')
    ->label('Amenities')
    ->columnSpanFull()
    ->relationship('amenities', 'name')
    ->options($options)
    ->pivotData(function ($record) {
        return [
            'amenity_type_id' => $record->amenity_type_id,
        ];
    })
    ->columns(3),

Looking for recommendations for this situation. Thanks!

To include amenity_type_id in the pivot table, you need to adjust the way you prepare your options and handle the pivot data
First don't use pluck instand use mapWithKeys
$options = Amenity::all()->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item->id => $item->name];
})
 

Then configure your pivotData
CheckboxList::make('amenities')
    ->label('Amenities')
    ->columnSpanFull()
    ->relationship('amenities', 'name', 'amenities.pivot.amenity_type_id')
    ->options($options)
        ->pivotData(function ($item, $state) {
            return ['amenity_type_id' => $item->amenity_type_id];
         })
     ->columns(3),

